# Nested div height in percentages not working if parent element haven't height

Tags: html, css, nested, height, percentage

Sometimes there are situations when you need to assign height of multi level nested divs in percentages f.e: I have nested divs here `<div class="outer"> <div class="middle"> <div class="inner" style="height: 100%"></div> </div> </div>` as you can see there are three nested divs and "inner" div has height 100% but the height of inner div is not visible while middle and outer divs have not height in pixels or percentages. Is there any solution that I wouldn't assign parent divs height and inner div's height would be visible in result?

Comment: Maybe using padding?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to give the parent a height, as the child divs heights are always relative to the parent element. I could be wrong, but I have never seen otherwise.